# Query app pictures through Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been reading through Facebook's graph api documentation and I've found a call to read an app's profile picture:

```
GET graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{app-id}/picture
```

Is there a way to query the rest of the app images (cover image, banner, web banner, app screenshots...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the docs to see which fields/edges can be queried:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application#Reading

Comment: Only the icon_url and logo_url can be queried according to the docs. Isn't there a way to get the screenshots/pictures shown in the App Center?

Comment: I don't think so, at least not via the Graph API.